# How can I replace array elements at varying index locations?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an array `x` that is 5x3 and all 0's.

```
x = numpy.zeros([5,3])
```

I wish to be able to replace some of those 0's with 1's at varying column indexes for each row.

For example, I'm looking for something like this

```
[[0,0,1],
 [0,1,0],
 [1,0,0],
 [0,1,0],
 [0,0,1]]
```

any fancy indexing technique that I know of will replace all of the 0's with 1's in one swoop or is too inflexible in index selection. For example, I can make the last two columns at each row 1's - basically, I can only replace values at the same column indexes in every row, but I want the column index at which I'm changing its value to vary from row to row.

Comment: Just do : `x[np.arange(5), [2,1,0,1,2]] = 1`.

Comment: thank you, this is perfect. I was doing x[:, [2,1,0,1,2]] = 1

Answer (score 1):

By using an [Index Array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) in a [Multidimensional array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) you can index into arbitrary locations.

So as mentioned in comments you can do:

```
x[np.arange(5), [2,1,0,1,2]] = 1
```